# Eclipse plug-in: configuration scope preference via preference page

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) for an Eclipse plug-in. This plugin will be packaged via the product file to be a standalone application. The installation will be a multi-user installation such as described in Scenario 2 of [this link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi%255Fuser%255Finstalls.html). So there will be one install area shared by many users.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1805577), I figured that I can set the `osgi.configuration.area` to a `user.home` location so that each user will have their own settings. I understand how to access the preferences [via code](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_load_and_save_plug-in_preferences?) but now I would like to be able to access these via the Preferences dialog under Window in Eclipse. For all the examples I have seen, the Preferences dialog only caters to Instance scope preferences. Is there any way for me to add Configuration scope preferences to the preferencesPage.

I have also viewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5795901) on stackoverflow but again this caters to Instance scope, hence I posted a separate question.

Comment: Somehow you need to get this value set in the .ini file -Declipse.pluginCustomization=cwide.properties in runtime based on user.home, maybe if user.home is a valid value in the ini customize it to point to user.home/preferences.properties?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by your comment... is that related to the preferences page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your preference page is a subclass of [PreferencePage](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/PreferencePage.html) (most likely a subclass of [FieldEditorPreferencePage](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/preference/FieldEditorPreferencePage.html)).

By implementing the [IWorkbenchPreferencePage](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPreferencePage.html) interface, you can implement the [init](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPreferencePage.html#init%28org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbench%29) method and set a custom [PreferenceStore](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/preferences/ScopedPreferenceStore.html) to be used in your implementation.

For example

```
public void init(IWorkbench workbench) {
    setPreferenceStore(
            new ScopedPreferenceStore(ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE, 
                    "com.nem.plugin") );
    setDescription("A preference page using configuration scope");
}
```

Comment: This is actually what I eventually implemented and for my performOK() and performDefaults(), I use ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.get() and put(), wherever necessary. Thank you!